# Elements changing position on different screen sizes

Tags: java, libgdx, screen-resolution

So I run my app on my phone and everything is fine ofcourse since I´ve been developing towards it. Then I tried running the app on my tablet and my `textBoxes` appears in completely different places at the screen. Im using Libgdx framework and this is what the class looks like:

```
public class StoneScreen implements Screen {

OrthographicCamera camera;
final TombStone game;

//Textures and art.
public Texture background, sdStone, arrowBack;
public Sprite backgrounds;

//TextField´s stuff
private Stage stage;
private Skin skin;
ImageButton btnArrow;
float screenWidth, screenHeight, stoneHeight, stoneWidth;

//private FitViewport viewport;

public StoneScreen(TombStone gam)    {
    this.game = gam;

    //Set´s the current device´s height and width into a float for easier usage
   screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
   screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

   //Set´s the tombstones height and width
   stoneHeight = screenHeight * 0.60f;
   stoneWidth = screenWidth *0.60f;

   //viewport = new FitViewport(camera, screenWidth, screenHeight)

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    game.assets.load();
    loadStandard();

}

public void loadStandard(){
    background = game.assets.background;
    sdStone = game.assets.sdStone;
    //backgrounds = Assets.backgrounds;
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Recieves the screen width and height
    float gameHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    float gameWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();


    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);


    game.batch.begin();
    Gdx.app.log("X", "FPS:" + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond());



    game.batch.draw(background,0,0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    game.batch.draw(sdStone, screenWidth *0.20f, screenHeight * 0.20f, screenWidth * 0.60f, screenHeight * 0.60f);

    //SpriteBatch batcher = (SpriteBatch)stage.getBatch();


    game.batch.end();

    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void show() {    

    //Generates the new font
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("NothingYouCouldDoBold.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 30;
    BitmapFont textFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    generator.dispose(); //Avoiding memory leaks.




Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("preferences");

Skin skin = new Skin();
Skin textSkin = new Skin();

stage = new Stage();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
//Sets skin
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
//Sets a color to the new font
Color fontcolor = Color.BLACK;

//Sets a new font to the textare n the textfield
TextFieldStyle textstyle = new TextFieldStyle();
textstyle.font = textFont;
textstyle.fontColor = fontcolor;

final TextArea textArea = new TextArea(prefs.getString("textArea", "Enter text:"), textstyle);
textArea.setX(420);
textArea.setY(700);
textArea.setWidth(350);
textArea.setHeight(350);
textArea.setMaxLength(50);


final TextField textField = new TextField(prefs.getString("textField", "Enter name:"), textstyle);

    textField.setX(420);
    textField.setY(800);
    textField.setMaxLength(20);
    textField.setWidth(350);
    textField.setHeight(100);





    //String text = Gdx.app.getPreferences("prefs").getString("text", "Default text if missimg");
    //TextField textField = new TextField(text, skin);

    //Backbutton 
            ImageButtonStyle styleTwo = new ImageButtonStyle();
            TextureRegionDrawable arrowImage = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("arrowLeft.png")));
            styleTwo.up = skin.newDrawable(skin.newDrawable(arrowImage));
            styleTwo.down = skin.newDrawable(skin.newDrawable(arrowImage));

            //Back button
    btnArrow = new ImageButton(styleTwo);

    btnArrow.setSize(150, 150);
    btnArrow.setPosition(450, 10);

    stage.addActor(textArea);
    stage.addActor(textField);
    stage.addActor(btnArrow);


    //Backbutton takes us back to mainmenu
            btnArrow.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                    game.setScreen(new MainScreen(game));


                    //Saves the entered text.

                    Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("preferences");
                    prefs.putString("textField", textField.getText());
                    prefs.putString("textArea", textArea.getText());
                    prefs.flush();
                }


            });

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub.

}
}
```

I really can´t figure out how to solve this. I tried google some solutions but they haven´t been to any help. It´s the TextField and TextArea that is giving me trouble.

Comment: I think this may help you https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: @AngelAngel is right, the `Viewport`s are made to solve this problem. Some of them support virtual width and height, and scale this virtual size up/down to fit the real `Screen`. So you don't need to take care about pixels, but you can calculate everything in your own, preffered unit. They also take care about different aspect ratios, for example they stretch things to fit the real aspect ratio or they show black borders to fit the desired aspect ratio.